# Client.connect galileo gen2 not working

Tags: c++, ethernet, arduino-galileo

I'm having a problem with the intel galileo gen2 ethernet. I am trying to get a webpage, but I can only connect to the ethernet, not the webpage.
I get this in the Serial monitor:
[image: Serial monitor output]

My code:

```
/*
  Web client

 This sketch connects to a website (http://www.google.com)
 using an Arduino Wiznet Ethernet shield.

 Circuit:
 * Ethernet shield attached to pins 10, 11, 12, 13

 created 18 Dec 2009
 by David A. Mellis
 modified 9 Apr 2012
 by Tom Igoe, based on work by Adrian McEwen

 */

#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

// Enter a MAC address for your controller below.
// Newer Ethernet shields have a MAC address printed on a sticker on the shield
byte mac[] = { 0x98, 0x4f, 0xee, 0x01, 0x8d, 0xdf };
// if you don't want to use DNS (and reduce your sketch size)
// use the numeric IP instead of the name for the server:
IPAddress server(216, 58, 217, 206); // numeric IP for Google (no DNS)
//char server[] = "www.google.com";    // name address for Google (using DNS)

// Set the static IP address to use if the DHCP fails to assign
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 177);
IPAddress dns(192, 168, 1, 122);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 1, 1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetClient client;

void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for Leonardo only
  }
  delay(5000);
  // start the Ethernet connection:

  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, dns, gateway, subnet);
  Serial.println("connected to ethernet");
  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(1000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");

  // if you get a connection, report back via serial:
  int ch = client.connect(server, 80);
  if (ch) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.println("GET /search?q=arduino HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host: www.google.com");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println();
  }
  else {
    // kf you didn't get a connection to the server:
    Serial.print("connection failed, error code ");
    Serial.println(ch);
  }
}

void loop()
{
  // if there are incoming bytes available
  // from the server, read them and print them:
  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  // if the server's disconnected, stop the client:
  if (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println("disconnecting.");
    client.stop();

    // do nothing forevermore:
    while (true);
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

6 months after figuring out the answer, I found this question again. I solved this question by adding `system("ifup eth0")` which completely solved the problem.